# Logger returning Handler size as 0. Why?

Tags: java, java.util.logging

Logger is returning Handler size as `0` but still logging statements in the console.

```
package com.amarpandey;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.amarpandey.test");

        System.out.println("Number of Handlers : " + logger.getHandlers().length);

        logger.severe("severe");
        logger.warning("warning");

    }
}
```

On executing the above code, the size of the handler array size inside Logger as `0`. But still I can see, all logs in console.

**OUTPUT IN CONSOLE:**

```
Number of Handlers : 0
Oct 01, 2018 3:54:19 PM com.amarpandey.Test main
SEVERE: severe
Oct 01, 2018 3:54:19 PM com.amarpandey.Test main
WARNING: warning
```

Comment: These logs are probably generated by handlers on a parent logger (such as the root logger). If you don't want that, you have to configure the logger to not pass things up the chain.

Comment: Thanks, Thillo, that really helped. I didn't know about root logger thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could use the parent's handler, see the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#addHandler(java.util.logging.Handler)):

> By default, Loggers also send their output to their parent logger.

And try:

```
System.out.println(logger.getParent().getHandlers().length); // 1
```